# Vertical scrolling in a master view that contains UICollectionView and UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview

I currently have a view set up in Storyboard comprised of an `UIImageView` on top and a `UICollectionView`.  The `UIImageView` has a fixed height, while the `UICollectionView` has a variable height depending on the number of cells associated with it.

[image]

What I am trying to figure out is how to set up the scrolling so that the entire master view could scroll vertically, meaning that the `UIImageView` would not stay locked on the top, and that when I scroll past a certain height in the `UICollectionView` it could then perform some action such as downloading more items to placed into additional cells?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your focus is on header view of collection view.

Refer to [this](http://www.appcoda.com/supplementary-view-uicollectionview-flow-layout/) for complete understanding:

Comment: Great suggestion.  Makes it much easier to work with too - thanks!